# Select the variables in one dataframe from a list in another dataframe

Tags: r, subset

I have a big data with large number of columns and rows. I want to subset few columns in df1 from a list of variables (the name of the columns in df1) in df2. Just for example, I have

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=sample(1:10, 10), B=sample(1:10, 10), C=sample(1:10,10), D=sample(1:10,10))
var <- c('A','C')
ratio <- c(0.5,0.6)
df2 <- data.frame(var,ratio)
```

New dataframe should look like this:

```
    A  C 
1   9  2 
2   1  3 
3   4  5 
4   2  8 
5  10  7 
6   5  1 
7   7  9 
8   3  4 
9   8 10 
10  6  6
```

Comment: Try `df1[as.character(df2$var)]` as the `var` is a `factor` column, convert it to `character`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to convert the `factor` variable 'var' to `character` class for subsetting the first dataset

```
df1[as.character(df2$var)]
```